# Duplicating a single row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a function:

```
def dupRow(df, val):
```

which takes a DataFrame, and a value. it finds the row in the 'val' column and duplicates just that row. So, for example if df=

```
 val  data1  data2  data3
0   a      3      1      9
1   b     89      2      8
2   c      7      3      7
3   d      0      4      6
```

then  `dupRow(df, 'c')` returns:

```
  val  data1  data2  data3
0   a      3      1      9
1   b     89      2      8
2   c      7      3      7
3   c      7      3      7
4   d      0      4      6
```

It can put the duplicated row at the bottom, I can reorder rows when I'm done, it's just easier to see this way.

I've seen a bunch of things using np.repeat, but I can't figure out how to get it to that only once rather than on the entire index...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually we do `reindex`

```
row = 'c'
out = df.reindex(df.index.append(df.index[df.val==row])).sort_index()
Out[27]: 
  val  data1  data2  data3
0   a      3      1      9
1   b     89      2      8
2   c      7      3      7
2   c      7      3      7
3   d      0      4      6
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, try:

```
def dupRow(df, val):
    return df.append(df[df["val"].eq(val)]).sort_values("val").reset_index(drop=True)

>>> dupRow(df, 'c')
  val  data1  data2  data3
0   a      3      1      9
1   b     89      2      8
2   c      7      3      7
3   c      7      3      7
4   d      0      4      6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Index.repeat`:

```
def dupRow(df, val):
    return df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['val'].eq('c').astype(int).add(1)))

>>> dupRow(df, 'c')
  val  data1  data2  data3
0   a      3      1      9
1   b     89      2      8
2   c      7      3      7
2   c      7      3      7
3   d      0      4      6
```

Just for information, it's probably not significative:

```
def dupRow_zabop(df, val):
    return df[df.val!=val].append([df[df.val==val]]*2)

def dupRow_not_speshal(df, val):
    return df.append(df[df["val"].eq(val)]).sort_values("val").reset_index(drop=True)

def dupRow_beny(df, val):
    return df.reindex(df.index.append(df.index[df.val==val])).sort_index()

def dupRow_corralien(df, val):
    return df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['val'].eq('c').astype(int).add(1)))
```

```
%timeit dupRow_zabop(df, 'c')
744 µs ± 3.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit dupRow_not_speshal(df, 'c')
714 µs ± 3.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit dupRow_beny(df, 'c')
393 µs ± 1.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit dupRow_corralien(df, 'c')
345 µs ± 1.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`append` is a more expensive operation compared to `reindex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def dupRow(df, val):
    return df[df.val!=val].append([df[df.val==val]]*2)
```

**Example:**

```
data = {'val': [1,2,3,4],
        'col2': ['a','b','c','d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df` is:

```
   val col2
0    1    a
1    2    b
2    3    c
3    4    d
```

`dupRow(df,3)` returns:

```
   val col2
0    1    a
1    2    b
3    4    d
2    3    c
2    3    c
```

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted another answer but because my case was SLIGHTLY different, I figured I'd post my actual solution here:

In the actual case, I have a large DF, and rather than wanting to duplicate all of the rows with val=='c', I want to duplicate ONE row of every set that have a duplicated val... so if there are 3 rows with val=='c', I duplicate the first one... what I ended up doing is:

```
data['nonDup'] = 1
counts = data.groupby(indexCol).count()['nonDup']
dups = [c for c in counts.index if counts[c] > 1]

for d in dups:
    dupData = data[data[indexCol]==d]
    dupInds = dupData.index.tolist()
    data = data.append(data.loc[dupInds[0]], ignore_index=True)
    
    data.loc[dupInds, 'nonDup'] = 0
```

I think that "ignore_index=True" is easier than going through the reindexing...